# Binded WPF Rectangle.Fill is not updating when source is set for the first time

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, rectangles

I have a very primitive colorpicker tool (in WPF). Here's how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, you can set the color by HSV or RGB on these very ugly sliders :) and the Fill property of the `Rectangle` gets updated.

For reasons not to be discussed, this ColorPicker is a UserControl.

It has truckloads of DependencyProperties (mostly for the color manipulation): Hue, Sat, Value, R,G,B; and the mixed colors of these values: RGBColor and HSVColor.

Here's the culprit RGBColor:

```
public Color RGBColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(RGBColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RGBColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RGBColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RGBColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RGBColor", typeof(Color), typeof(SimpleColorPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent, (d, e) =>
        {
            var colorpicker = d as SimpleColorPicker;
            if (e.NewValue != null && colorpicker != null)
            {
                
                var c = (Color)e.NewValue;

                if (c.R != colorpicker.R) colorpicker.R = c.R;
                if (c.G != colorpicker.G) colorpicker.G = c.G;
                if (c.B != colorpicker.B) colorpicker.B = c.B;

                colorpicker.RGBBrush = new SolidColorBrush(colorpicker.RGBColor);

                if (colorpicker._fromRGB)
                {
                    var hsv = HSVColor.FromColor(c);
                    if (colorpicker.HSVColor == null || !colorpicker.HSVColor.Equals(hsv))
                        colorpicker.HSVColor = hsv;
                }

                colorpicker.forceDisplayRefresh();
            }

        }));
```

In the XAML part I use the following for getting the RGBColor to the Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Height="100" x:Name="DisplayRectangle">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RGBColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

(DataContext at this point is the control itself, because I didn't want to use FindAncestor on all the bindings, so  in the ColorPicker constructor I have `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;` where LayoutRoot is the root Grid of the control.)

I'm trying to use this control in View. I have a VM for the View that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a notify-property (is that how it's called?)

```
public Color Color
{
    get { return _color; }
    set
    {
        _color = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Color);
    }
}
```

I'd like to edit this property with the Colorpicker (DataContext is the VM):

```
<base:SimpleColorPicker RGBColor="{Binding Color}"/>
```

The editing itself works. `Color` property gets set in the VM when I adjust the sliders on the colorpicker.

However, when I load a VM that already has Color set, the `Rectangle` won't update. The sliders do, and all the `DependencyProperties` get set to the right value, but the Rectangle's Fill just won't change. (It stay `Transparent` which is the default value of the `RGBColor DependencyProperty`).
(again, after loading, if I adjust the sliders, the Rectangle updates again...)

**Things that have already failed:**

- I've tried using a Brush and bind the Fill property directly (instead
  of Fill.Color)
- I've tried directly updating the binding on
  Rectangle.Fill

What more is there to try and make this work?

Comment: Don't know why the Binding won't work initially. However, wouldn't it be a much simpler approach *not* to bind the Rectangle's Fill property to the `RGBColor` property, but simply set `((SolidColorBrush)DisplayRectangle.Fill).Color = RGBColor;` in your `forceDisplayRefresh()` method?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works now, but I'm really curious what happens in the background that I don't see... Must be something trivial... :)